# Python: use parent class instance variable to set child instance variable

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance, multiple-inheritance

Let's say I have a class like

```
Parent(Super1, Super2):  
    var1 = "apples"
...

Child(Parent):
    if var1 == "apples":
        var2 = "red"
    elif var1 == "oranges";
        var2 = "orange"
```

I get an `unresolved reference` error when I try something like this. I know I can access the value of the parent instance variable by making a method and using `self`, but I have a circumstance where I need to do this outside of a method (because it should happen as soon as the class is instantiated). I also cant implement `__init__` because my parent class doesn't use `__init__`.How can I accomplish accessing the value of the parent's instance variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an instance variable as currently defined, instead it is a class variable. Thus you can access it by using the class name: `Parent.var1`